# What's the difference between these two MySQL connect approaches

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm learning PHP. I've seen these two approaches to connecting to a MySQL database.

Could someone explain what's the difference between them, and why the second approach doesn't work in a standard form submission (is there a syntax error I have missed)?

Approach 1 (works):

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("$mysql_server", "$mysql_user", "$mysql_pw", "$mysql_db");
if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: (" . $mysqli->connect_errno . ") " . $mysqli->connect_error;
}
```

Approach 2 (throws a server error):

```
$link = mysqli_connect("$mysql_server", "$mysql_user", "$mysql_pw", "$mysql_db");
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what does that mean?  Can you be more specific about what is not working the way you expect it to?

Comment: It throws a "server error" in the second instance, but not the first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Approach 1 is the object oriented approach. Approach 2 is the procedural approach.

Comment: Practically, what's the difference?

Comment: @alias51 aside from the way in which you choose to write the code, nothing.

Answer (score -1):

Approach 1 is object oriented while 2 is procedural.

Code for Your Help is :

```
// connection
$link = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link));

//consultation

$query = "SELECT name FROM mytable" or die("Error in the consult.." . mysqli_error($link));

//execute the query.

$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

//display information:`enter code here`

while($row = mysqli_fecth_array($result)) {
  echo $row["name"] . "<br>";
}
```